# is it possible to allocate an unname memory and then associate pointers in fortran?

Tags: pointers, fortran, mpi, shared-memory

My question is motivated by the custom fortran datatypes. an example is given as follows:

```
type mytype
    integer, pointer :: a(:)
    real, pointer :: b(:)
end type 

type(mytype), pointer :: data(:)
! this MPI routine reserves a memory region
call mpi_win_allocate_shared(size,disp_unit,...,baseptr,win,ierr)

! is the following achievable? 
do i = 1,n1
    call c_to_f_pointer(baseptr + offset_i, data)
    call c_to_f_pointer(baseptr + offset_ij, data(i)%a)
    call c_to_f_pointer(baseptr + offset_ik, data(i)%b)
enddo
```

Comment: The above is all very confusing. Firstly `integer, pointer :: a(:)` is *not* an array of pointers to integer, it is a pointer to an array of integers. Secondly in Fortran you can't do pointer arithmetic (thank god!), either with Fortran pointers or type( c_ptr ) - for the later the `+` operator is not overloaded. Basically you are trying to write C in Fortran, but they are different languages and may express similar ideas in very different ways. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @IanBush, Hi Ian thanks for the comment. It is not confusing actually, you described what just what I wanted, i.e., a(:) is a pointer to an array of integers.   Now the reason I wanted pointers is because I want to store a fortran custom data type using MPI_shared, and access it between various processes. I only know how to do it using C pointers but my work requires that I use fortran.

Comment: `c_f_pointer` returns a Fortran pointer as its second argument. As written you have it returning an integer. real or type(mytype), but you might think it a pointer if you had the misunderstanding I alluded to - hence my confusion

Comment: you are right about the wrong code I have provide Ian. I have thus updated it, and hopefully it makes sense now.  I hope my question still makes sense, i.e., since fortran does not support pointer arithmetic, how should I have the pointers data, data(i)%a and data(i)%b correctly point to a pre-allocated block of memory using MPI

Comment: OK, trying to think through what you might be wanting to do replacing all the loops part with simply `Call c_f_pointer( baseptr, data, [ n1 ] )`  might do what you want if you make your derived type interoperable. But as I'm not sure quite what you want I won't try to answer, at least not yet.

Comment: @IanBush --- here's what I want to do:  I need to use MPI to initiate multiple instances of fortran code to perform a numerical calculation. Different MPI processes run independently, except that they all share the same huge data structure. As a result, it makes sense to use MPI_allocate_shared to only create the data structure once, and have other MPI processes directly read from it.   However, being a custom-defined type, it is not clear how to instruct other MPI processes to know the data structure. In C this can be achieved via pointer arithmetics. However in fortran it is not clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234923/discussion-between-rain-and-ian-bush).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, you want to chop up one area of (shared) memory and have different pointers point to different bits of it, *and* have different processes be able to read it. Never done this before, here's my first best guess. It assumes that all data you want to use occupies an integer multiple of the number of bytes used to represent an integer:

```
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpif90 --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpif90 --showme:version
mpif90: Open MPI 4.0.3 (Language: Fortran)
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ cat shared2.f90
Program main 

  Use, Intrinsic :: iso_c_binding  , Only : c_ptr, c_loc, c_f_pointer, c_int, c_double
  Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only : numeric_storage_size
  
  Use mpi_f08, Only : mpi_address_kind, mpi_comm_world, mpi_info, mpi_win, &
       mpi_info_null, mpi_proc_null, mpi_init, mpi_comm_size, mpi_comm_rank, &
       mpi_win_allocate_shared, mpi_win_shared_query, mpi_win_fence, &
       mpi_win_free, mpi_free_mem, mpi_finalize

  Implicit None ( Type, External )

  
  Integer, Parameter :: n_int   = 2 ! number of ints in the structure
  Integer, Parameter :: n_real  = 3 ! number of reals in the structures
  Integer, Parameter :: n_stuff = 4 ! number of elements in the array of structures

  Type :: my_struct
     Integer( c_int    ), Dimension( : ), Pointer :: value1
     Real   ( c_double ), Dimension( : ), Pointer :: value2
  End type my_struct
  
  Type( my_struct ), Dimension( : ), Allocatable :: stuff
  Type( mpi_info  ) :: info 
  Type( mpi_win   ) :: window
  Type( c_ptr     ) :: baseptr

  Integer( c_int ), Dimension( : ), Pointer :: shared_memory
  
  Integer( mpi_address_kind ) :: bytes

  Integer :: size_int, size_real
  Integer :: size_shared
  Integer :: disp_unit
  Integer :: w_rank, w_size, ierr
  Integer :: point
  Integer :: i
  
  Call mpi_init( ierr )
  Call mpi_comm_size( mpi_comm_world, w_size, ierr )
  Call mpi_comm_rank( mpi_comm_world, w_rank, ierr )

  Allocate( stuff( 1:n_stuff ) )
  
  size_int  = storage_size( stuff( 1 )%value1 ) / numeric_storage_size
  size_real = storage_size( stuff( 1 )%value2 ) / numeric_storage_size

  info = mpi_info_null
  disp_unit = 1
  If( w_rank == 0 ) Then
     bytes = n_stuff * ( size_int * n_int + size_real * n_real )
  Else
     bytes = 0
  End If
  Call mpi_win_allocate_shared( bytes, disp_unit, info, mpi_comm_world, baseptr, window, ierr )
  Call mpi_win_shared_query( window, mpi_proc_null, bytes, disp_unit, baseptr, ierr )

  size_shared = Int( bytes / size_int, Kind = Kind( size_shared ) )
  Call c_f_pointer( baseptr, shared_memory, [ size_shared ] )
  point = 1
  Do i = 1, n_stuff
     Call c_f_pointer( C_loc( shared_memory( point ) ), stuff( i )%value1, [ n_int ] )
     point = point + n_int
     Call c_f_pointer( C_loc( shared_memory( point ) ), stuff( i )%value2, [ n_real ] )
     point = point + n_real * ( size_real / size_int )
  End Do

  If( w_rank == 0 ) Then
     Do i = 1, Size( stuff )
        stuff( i )%value1 = 1 * i
        stuff( i )%value2 = 2.0_c_double * i
     End Do
  End If
  Call mpi_win_fence( 0, window, ierr )

  If( w_rank == 2 ) Then
     Do i = 1, Size( stuff )
        Write( *, * ) stuff( i )%value1, stuff( i )%value2
     End Do
  End If

  Call mpi_win_free( window, ierr )

  Call mpi_finalize( ierr )
  
End Program main
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpif90 -Wall -Wextra -fcheck=all -O -g -std=f2018 shared2.f90
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpirun -np 3 ./a.out 
           1           1   2.0000000000000000        2.0000000000000000        2.0000000000000000     
           2           2   4.0000000000000000        4.0000000000000000        4.0000000000000000     
           3           3   6.0000000000000000        6.0000000000000000        6.0000000000000000     
           4           4   8.0000000000000000        8.0000000000000000        8.0000000000000000     
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ mpirun -np 3 ./a.out 
           1           1   2.0000000000000000        2.0000000000000000        2.0000000000000000     
           2           2   4.0000000000000000        4.0000000000000000        4.0000000000000000     
           3           3   6.0000000000000000        6.0000000000000000        6.0000000000000000     
           4           4   8.0000000000000000        8.0000000000000000        8.0000000000000000
```